# Explain overloading streams with pointers and typedef

Tags: c++, overloading, typedef, operator-keyword

I have the following code in my .h/.cpp files:

.h:

```
class Foo;
typedef Foo * pFoo;

class Foo {
public:
    char c;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Foo &f);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const pFoo &f);
```

.cpp:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Foo &f) { out << f.c; return out; }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const pFoo &f) { out << f->c; return out; }
```

In main when I run the following code:

```
Foo f;
f.c = 'a';
std::cout << "As foo object:" << f << std::endl;
std::cout << "As foo pointer:" << &f << std::endl;
```

I get the output:

```
As foo object:a
As foo pointer:a
```

But, if, for instance, I replace my typedef with:

```
#define pFoo Foo*
```

Instead I get the output:

```
As foo object:a
As foo pointer:0x7fff5fbff980
```

I know you cannot overload operators for built-in types. Is typedef really creating a new type, or is it just an alias for the existing type? The answer seems to be that it is creating a new type. I'm basically looking for a deeper explanation between the difference in behavior. (I'm not trying to do this in production code.)

Comment: IMHO, you're better off neither using `#define` nor `typedef` to create a "pointer type". It's much clearer to just use the `*` where needed to declare pointers, and it avoids surprises like this. Also, the [Linux Coding Standards](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) disallow creation of pointer types with typedef. From Chapter 5: "It's a *mistake* to use `typedef` for structures and pointers. When you see a `vps_t a;` in the source, what does it mean? In contrast, if it says `struct virtual_container *a;` you can actually tell what `a` is."

Comment: I don't disagree. I was more playing around with different variants on the code to see how things worked, and couldn't explain the difference I was seeing. Your comments are, or course, correct and good to have here for someone looking at this page for different reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is typedef really creating a new type, or is it just an alias for the existing type?

`typedef` introduces aliases or synonyms for types.

What happens here is that when you use the typedef, `const pFoo` is a `const` pointer to a `Foo`.
When you just replace `pFoo` with `Foo*` using a define, the function argument is `const Foo*`, which is a pointer to a `const Foo`.

Try out the following variations as the parameter type:

```
const Foo * &
Foo const * &
Foo * const &
```

Note that as you can always dereference pointers, there shouldn't be any need for the second overload:

```
Foo *p = &f;
std::cout << *p << std::endl;
```

Comment: And in the latter case, he doesn't have an `operator <<` that matches it, so the compiler chose the overload for `void *`.

Comment: Right; `Foo* const &f` gave me the desired results. I was just totally overlooking the differences.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case no `operator <<` overload match, so, standard one for pointers is used.

When you use `typedef Foo * pFoo;`, you alias `Foo*` with `pFoo`. Then, const `pFoo` will mean `const (pFoo *)` that is `pFoo* const`, *constant pointer to Foo*. As `&f` can match `const pFoo*`, your 2nd overload used.

`#define pFoo Foo *` simply replays `pFoo' with`Foo*`. As a rfesult`const pFoo`expands into`const Foo*`, _pointer to constant Foo`. `&f` does not macth this, that's why standard overload for pointer used.